# Can I use fiberglass shower drain for tile base?

Tags: plumbing, shower, tile, drain

I pulled out my fiberglass shower enclosure and replace with a tile base.
I only found this drain in stock

[image]

Is it OK just to use that? This is basement shower and concrete foundation. So basically I will remove the white nut and plastic/paper gasket and tile up to the lip of the threaded pipe inside. I guess it will be hard to make adjustment up and down on the cover, right?

OR do I use this kinda of shower drain?

[image]

There is also a round version but none are available in stock and I have to wait few weeks...

**UPDATE 1**

This is the plumbing with 1.5" pipe with male threaded

[image]

NOTE: I know 1.5" is not up to code as 2" is required. But this is in basement concrete foundation and I am not planning to make a big mess. 1.5" works fine for me many years.

This is the piece that screw in the male pipe before when there was a fiberglass shower pan

[image]

That white piece is basically a female 1.5" to 2" male.

That piece is already raising the level like 1". So the less height, the better for me. "That" is why I was thinking about using the thinner version of another fiberglass drain assembly.

Answer (score 1):

The [**Oatey 1-1/2" shower drain**](https://www.ferguson.com/product/oatey-1-12-in-ips-cast-iron-shower-drain-o42192/_/R-928580) is designed specifically for this type of application. It looks similar to your first photo and you won't have to use a 2" to 1-1/2" reducer.

[image: 1-1/2" SHower Drain]

If you need more adjustment, you could go with a **[Pro-Flo adjustable shower drain](https://www.ferguson.com/product/proflo-2-x-1-12-in-abs-adjustable-shower-drain-pf42808/_/A-ProdFamily-176166)**.

[image]

Comment: The second one is ideal but I am hesitate to see "Call for Pricing". Also it didn't have female treaded 1.5" https://api.ferguson.com/dar-step-service/Query?USE_TYPE=SPECIFICATION&PRODUCT_ID=4483309